# Laravel - Deleting a row (table)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, routes, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I'm studying the manipulation of datas with Eloquent. I have a table in which I need to delete a row with a button.

**Problem** : The server returns a route error (NotFoundHttpException)

**Guideline** : I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EyoZhfZ2TY in order to inspire me for the datas.

Here is the Route (**routes.php**)

```
Route::delete('players&/{id}', 'PlayersController@deletePlayer');
```

Here is the template (**players.blade.php**) Pay attention of the last table data (td)

```
     <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($players as $player) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_ID?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Name?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Surname?></td>
        <td><?php echo $player->PLA_Pseudo?></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
        <td><a href="delete&<?php echo $player->PLA_ID?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    ?>
    </tbody>
```

Finally the function (**PlayersController.php**)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Player;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class PlayersController extends Controller
{
public function show(){ // reçoit l'url http://monsite.fr/users avec le      verbe "get" et qui retourne le formulaire.

    $players = player::all();
    return view('players', ['players' => $players]);
}

public function insertPlayer(){
    $player = new Player;

    $player->PLA_Name = Input::get('nom', false);
    $player->PLA_Surname = Input::get('prenom', false);
    $player->PLA_Pseudo = Input::get('pseudo', false);

    $player->save();

    return redirect('players');
}

public function deletePlayer($id){

    Player::destroy($id);
    return redirect('players');
}
```

}

I will search on my side too and thank you for taking time on my problem =)

P.S. I need the best practices with this framework, so if you have some ideas that allow me to code better, I could help some beginners like me =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change route to:

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', 'PlayersController@deletePlayer');
```

Change anchor to:

```
<a href="{{ url('delete', $player->PLA_ID) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Anchor tags always make GET requests. Which is why the route needs to be a GET route. Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what you mean, thank you but I don't know why, I have this error : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `players` where `id` in (7)). Edit : I searched everywhere but I have PLA_ID in my column name in phpmyadmin. I'm working on it.

Comment: @Arkhall Can you update your post to show the code for `PlayersController@deletePlayer`?

Comment: The function had no changements, but here is all my file PlayersController

Comment: The solution was found for the route (that was the topic). Thank you for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

Your route is incorrect. Chnage it some thing like

```
Route::post('/delete/{id}',[
    'uses' => 'PlayersController@deletePlayer'
]);
```

html anchor:

```
<a href="{{ url('/delete/') }}<?php echo $player->PLA_ID?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you but the server don't find the route, I will work with your answer and adapt it, maybe I made a mistake.